# Is something like keylistener in c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

What i need is after move with mouse on button call function. In java, there is mouselistener and method what do it. How i can make it in C# WPF? Is there something similar?

I tried google but find nothing.

Comment: Do you mean you want to detect when the mouse has moved over a button?

Comment: google keylogger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add element on XAML

```
<Button ....... MouseMove="Button1MouseMove">
```

in your **file.cs**

```
private void Button1MouseMouve(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
    int mouse_x = position.x;
}
```